# What is this for a character `\ x9d`?

Tags: text, unicode, character-encoding

While parsing a text file and doing some prints for debug purposes, the print stucks at a point but I didn't get any errors and the script seemed be running further. So I checked the file content and I recognised a rectangle character. I copied it to the python interpreter and the interpreter got stuck as well.

I checked on [Unicode Lookup](https://unicodelookup.com) the character definition: `osc operating system command` and the unicode is `\x9d`. What does that mean?

This is the character how it looks here:

Edit: After posting I recognised, that the character is invisible. So I did a screenshot from the editing view, so you see the character from the edit mode perspective.[image]

Comment: It should not be in a normal Unicode text. So it may be a copy-paste error from the past (Ø in cp850 or ¥ in cp437). Or some editors used control codes to signal formatting changes. OSC is practically never used (and if it is used, it is used on terminals).